# Force Gnome app launcher to create new terminal

Tags: gnome, launcher, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

Whenever I launch gnome-terminal, terminator or some other terminal program via Gnome-Shell's app launcher, it brings to focus any existing window instead of creating a new one.

If I wanted to bring an existing window to focus...I'd do that. I'm using the launcher because I want to launch a new terminal window. How do I force Gnome-Shell to do that?

Comment: I don't know if that's true for Gnome too, but at least in Unity you get a context menu with a "New Terminal" button if you right-click on the gnome-terminal icon.

Answer (score 2):

Just click with the `middle mouse` button on the terminal icon in the launcher. This opens a second terminal window.

This Gnome extension makes launching a new instance the default action: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/600/launch-new-instance

Comment: I also accomodate with that, but isn't there a way to set things up properly ?

Comment: How do you mean? Can you define what does "properly" mean for you?

Comment: I mean, create a new instance on click, instead of having to right click and select the proper "New XYZ" option

Comment: But that is exactly what I have answered. With one -middle- click the new instance is opened. (There is one more catch but only if gnome is installed separately, then sometimes middle click doesn't work on launcher, in that case you need to install this `sudo apt-get install oxygen-cursor-theme`)

Comment: :-) No middle click on my touchpad :-)

Comment: Now i see what is your problem :)

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/600/launch-new-instance/

Comment: That is what I have found... let me know if it helps you

Comment: I feel so ashamed not to have found this myself. 
Works like a charm. Thank you so much !